# Content hugging in SwiftUI sidebar list

Tags: list, macos, swiftui

I have multiple lists in sidebar in a SwiftUI app. Some content is added to the lists dynamically outside of the lists. Problem is that the list is not hugging its content. I do have a spacer at the bottom but it does not help. This image shows the problem:

[image]

I tried different list style and tried different modifiers but list still does not hug its content.

Below is code which generated the UI in the image.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        VStack() {
            List(model.groups) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .background(.purple)
            Spacer()
        }
        Text("Something")
        Spacer()
        List(model.groups) { item in
            Text(item.name)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0,leading: 0,bottom: -20,trailing: 0))
        }
        .background(.blue)
        Text("Something")
        Spacer()

    } detail: {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. In the following code I replaced the top list with ForEach. This helps with content hugging but requires that each cell is formatted and it cannot support hierarchical list. For my use case this works. I can dynamically add items and remove them and list comes back to its size. Bottom list takes over rest of the sidebar. Which is not a problem at the moment as there is nothing under it. It is still good to know if the scrollview containing outline view in the list has something to make it hug content if its smaller than its frame.

```
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationSplitView {
        VStack() {
            ForEach(model.groups) { item in
                HStack{
                    Text(item.name)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 2, leading: 10, bottom: 2, trailing: 0))
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        }
        Text("Something")
        Spacer()
        List(model.groups) { item in
            Text(item.name)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0,leading: 0,bottom: -20,trailing: 0))
        }
        .background(.blue)
        Text("Something")
        Spacer()
    } detail: {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
```